# Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qpainter, qabstractbutton

I have seen many answers for the same Question, I have already gone through them but none them solved my problem, I am getting the error

> QWidget::paintEngine: Should no longer be called
>   QPainter::begin: Paint device returned engine == 0, type: 1
>   QPainter::end: Painter not active, aborted

I need to know,  What is type : 1, and why this error showing,

My code is

iconwidget.h

```
class IconWigdet : public QAbstractButton
{
Q_OBJECT
QRect *iconarea;
QPainter p;
QPixmap *icon; 
public:
explicit IconWigdet(QRect *rectangle,QPixmap *tempicon);
void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);  
};
```

iconwidget.cpp

```
IconWigdet::IconWigdet(QRect *rectangle,QPixmap *tempicon)
{
iconarea = new QRect();
*iconarea = *rectangle  ;
icon = new QPixmap(*tempicon);
this->setGeometry(0,0,iconarea->width(),iconarea->height()+20);
}

void IconWigdet::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
qDebug() << " PaintEvent ";
p.begin(this);
p.drawText(iconarea->x()+ 10,iconarea->height()+10, "name");
p.drawPixmap ( *iconarea,*icon );
p.end();
}
```

groupwidget.h

```
class GroupWidget: public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
QGridLayout *groupLayout = new QGridLayout ;
QRect *rect = new QRect( 0, 0, 100, 100);
QPixmap *pimap = new QPixmap("../widgeticon/icons/ball.png");
IconWigdet *icon = new IconWigdet(rect,pimap);
public:
GroupWidget();
};
```

groupwidget.cpp

```
GroupWidget::GroupWidget()
{ 
groupLayout->addWidget(icon, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0);
this->setLayout(groupLayout);
icon->show();
QPaintEvent *e;
icon->paintEvent(e);
}
```

main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);
GroupWidget *Gw = new GroupWidget;
Gw->show();
return a.exec();
}
```

and the iconwidget class will work perfectly if the main function changed to

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
QApplication a(argc, argv);;   
QRect *rect = new QRect( 0, 0, 100, 100);
QPixmap *pimap = new QPixmap("../widgeticon/icons/ball.png");
IconWigdet *Iw = new IconWigdet(rect,pimap);
Iw->show();
return a.exec();
}
```

that means, If we use iconwidget class object in main function it is working, but it is not working  when we do the same in groupwidget class,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't make changes that invalidate the answers you receive.  I've rolled back for you so that the accepted answer makes sense again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling `IconWigdet::paintEvent` directly. This is not allowed. Instead of calling it directly, call [`QWidget::update`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#update) or [`QWidget::repaint`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint).

```
GroupWidget::GroupWidget()
{ 
    groupLayout->addWidget(icon, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0);
    this->setLayout(groupLayout);
    icon->show();
    // QPaintEvent *e;
    // icon->paintEvent(e); this is not allowed
    icon->update(); // do this instead
}
```

Though I don't see why would you call anything there. Just calling `Icon->show();` should be enough. Qt will automatically schedule a paint event.

Comment: It is not working.. it is working when I am using simply Icon->show  in main function ( main function is mentioned in Qn).
It is not working when I am calling it in groupwidget class, actually the paint event is not invoking automatically or it is showing error when call from the groupwidget

Comment: @AkhilVSuku You're doing something strange in your `groupwidget.h`. Is this your actual header file?

Comment: @AkhilVSuku You also have needless pointers all over the place that you don't delete, so you have a bunch of memory leaks. Like `QRect *iconarea` and `QPixmap *icon`. There is no reason to have those as pointers. Only use pointers if you have a good reason to do so, don't just put them everywhere. Same goes for your `IconWidget` constructor, you could pass `const` references to it: `IconWigdet(const QRect &rectangle, const QPixmap &tempicon);`

Comment: groupwidget.h is the same file I am using, My doubt is why the paintEvent is not working when I create object in groupwidget class while it is working when I create object in main function.. Advance Thanks for your help,

Comment: @AkhilVSuku What happens if you set a minimum size for your `IconWigdet`? Just put `setMinimumSize(100,100);` in the constructor.

Comment: It is worked, thanks , but could you please explain why it was notworking in the other case,  why I  need to give 
`setMinimumSize(100,100);` in **groupwidget** (_in this case groupwidget object is called in main function to show_) ,  while it is not neccessary in **main** function

Comment: @AkhilVSuku You add your `IconWidget` to a layout which will take control of the widget's geometry. `setGeometry` does nothing for widgets that are inside a layout. In your case it seems that it went down to size `0,0`. However the layout will still respect the widget's minimum and maximum size. When you created your `IconWidget` in the `main` function, it wasn't in a layout, so `setGeometry` worked.

Comment: Ya that is why it is not working, now I got the mistake I made, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of your constructor

```
GroupWidget::GroupWidget()
{ 
    groupLayout->addWidget(icon, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0);
    this->setLayout(groupLayout);
    setMinimumSize(100,100); 
    setMaximumSize(200,200); 
    icon->show();
}
```

This will work,